# How to implement receive function outside actor scope and pass it to actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor, that can be in several states. Initial state should be passed from outside:

```
class MyActor(openId: String, initialState: Receive) extends Actor {

  val connected: (String) => Receive = (openId: String) => {
    case AuthorizedOk(user) => context.become(authorized(user))
    ...
    case message => unhandled(message)
  }

  val authorized: (IUserInfo) => Receive = (user: IUserInfo) => {
    case SomeLogic => context.become(...)
    case message => unhandled(message)
  }

  def receive: Actor.Receive = initialState
}
```

I need to set initial state `connected` or `authorized` in constructor. Of course it may be some other function. But i don't understand how to achieve this:

```
new MyActor("id", ???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities

1. Have the state passed in to the preStart lifecycle method of the actor

or

2. Have an object companion that can be used to pass the state when initialising the actor instance. Something in the lines of:

   object MyActor {

   def props(initialState: YourState) = Props.actorOf(new MyActor(initialState))

   }

Also the initial state in your example need not be a partial function. You could model that as a case class and just use context.become to move between the states as they evolve.

EDIT: Adding an example to be a bit more clear!

```
sealed trait State
case object Authorized extends State
case object UnAuthorized extends State

class MyActor(state: State) extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
   case state: State =>
     // do some logic
     val newState = someLogic(state)
     // evolve with the new state
     context.become(active(newState))
  }

  def active(newState: State): Receive = {
    // do the pattern matching on the state and evolve
  }

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    // send the initial state to this actor
    self ! state
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. My problem, that i don't understand(new to scala) how to implement receive function outside actor scope, so I can pass it to actor. Some examples would be nice!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Receive function is a function on the Actor class that you need to override when extending an Actor. And moreover the Actor reference that you get is just a Proxy to the underlying Actor instance, so you might not be able to call your methods or fields like you have on your example (authorized, connected) as such.